# Por qué falla en la fecha y no se crea el procedimiento?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, stored-procedure, mysqldb

Tengo problemas con crear ese procedimiento, no me reconoce el formato de fecha, lo que estoy haciendo es transformando código de *sql* a *mysql* pero no me reconoce el formato correcto para registrar la fecha en este procedimiento.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_ObtenerElecciones()
 begin
    SET DATE_FORMAT( NOW(),'%y%m%d');
    
    select e.IdEleccion,e.Descripcion,e.Cargo,e.Activo,e.FechaRegistro,
    u.IdUsuario,u.Correo  from ELECCIONES e
    join USUARIOS u on u.IdUsuario = e.IdUsuarioRegistro;
 end;
```

MySQL ha dicho:

```
Documentación

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '( NOW(),'%y%m%d');
    
    select e.IdEleccion,e.Descripcion,e.Cargo,e.Activo,e....' en la linea 3
```

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
No añadas en comentarios lo que puedes añadir editando la pregunta todas las veces que necesites. Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: ¿Con "sql" quieres decir _SQL Server_? Recuerda que sql es el lenguaje con el que construimos las consultas y demás instrucciones, que es independiente del Motor de Base de datos que usamos.

Comment: Y cómo está seteado el campo _FechaRegistro_ de tu tabla?

Answer (score 0):

A qué le quieres cambair el formato? Esa función no se usa como supones y está en la [documentación oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Intentas fijar un "formato para todas las fechas que haya en tu ejecución"? Creo que MySQL no ofrece eso y definitivamente no funcionaría como lo intentas (no estás modificando nada en el entorno, no le dices a qué debe asignarle ese NOW con ese formato).

Y si pruebas dándole formato al campo de fecha simplemente?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_ObtenerElecciones()
 begin    
    select 
        e.IdEleccion, e.Descripcion, 
        e.Cargo, e.Activo, 
        DATE_FORMAT( e.FechaRegistro,'%y%m%d') AS FechaRegistro,
        u.IdUsuario, u.Correo  
    from ELECCIONES e
    join USUARIOS u on u.IdUsuario = e.IdUsuarioRegistro;
 end;
```

Comment: Lo que entiendo esque ese procedimiento quiere registrar la fecha y hora de una lista de elecciones. Pero no reconoce la linea donde quiere añadir la fecha y ahora lo que contenga no importa, solo deseo crear el procedimiento segun lo que se entiende, no conosco mucho de mysql por eso pido de su ayuda si puedieran hacerlo funcional. Por otro lado acabo de usar el codigo que me brindastes pero me dio un ERROR DE ACCESO EN EL ESQUEMA DE INFORMACION.

Comment: @jojojo nosotros no sabemos qué quieres que el procedimiento haga; si no lo sabes tú, mucho menos nosotros (y te lo digo con toda la buena onda). Si intentas cosas adicionales y salen errores diferentes, no pongas resumenes de los errores y edita tu pregunta **añadiendo** la nueva información de lo que tampoco funciona

Comment: GRACIASSS SOLUCIONADO.. Alfabravo, el error de acceso parece que la conexion web de la BD se perdio por un momento por eso no me creaba el procedimiento con el codigo que me brindastes, pero actualize y probe denuevo, y acepto!

Comment: @jojojo súper! falta que confirmes si hace lo que necesitas o si falta algo más.